# How to make sure only one popover is activated at each time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following code that shows an ajax content for each element for my page.

```
function details_in_popup(link, div_id){
    $.ajax({
        url: link,
        success: function(response){
        $('#'+div_id).empty().html(response);
        }
    });
    return '<div id="'+ div_id +'">Loading...</div>';
}

$(function () {
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
        "html": true,
        "title": '<span class="text-info"><strong>Quick View</strong></span>' +
                '<button type="button" id="close" class="close" >&times;</button>',
        "content": function () {
            var div_id = $(this).data('id');
            return details_in_popup($(this).data('url'), div_id);
        }
    }).on('shown.bs.popover', function (e) {
        var popover = jQuery(this);
        $('body').on('click', '.close', function (e) {
            //popover.popover('hide');
            $(".popover").remove();
            $(this).data('id').remove();
        });
    });
});
```

And in the html i have :

```
<button data-url="<%= my_url %>" href="#" type="button" class="" data-container="body"  data-toggle="popover" data-id="<%= product.slug %>"  style="">Popover</button>
```

This code does the trick and shows the popover with the correct content, in the sense that the first time the popover opens. I have the normal behavour

But starting from the second time, i have 2 popovers one on top of the other, One with loading message, and the other with the content. Also the button of the loading popover is the one that can close both popovers.

First time popover:
[image]

Second time popover:
[image]

Do you have any idea on how could i get ride of the second loading popover and bind the close button the the popover that have the content ?

Thank you very much and i hope that i was clear in my explanation

Comment: i think you should use id or class like $('#yourid').popover({
your code
});

Comment: destroy the first before creating the second....`$('#yourid').popover('destroy')`

Answer (score 0):

I tried your html code. I think you need to add data content as well. data-content="your text here". Rest seems to be fine. And for close functionality just add data-trigger = "focus". click here http://www.bootply.com/ZkPQGSAkbq

If you need a close button here is an example. This might help you figure out. [][1]

```
    [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/erik1337/fvE22/
```